# Glyphicons search can not be viewed correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I try to put a search icon beside the search form, but it can not work. I tried some solution here but none can work. What should I do?

And this is the source code

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

When you use glyphicons, you must always add single class "glyphicon". You can see, the example on bootstrap3 [components page](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use)

**Wrong usage**

```
<i class="glyphicon-search"></i>
```

**Correct usage**

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
```